# GSconnect downloaded not working

Tags: gnome

I have downloaded and extracted GSConnect (Shell 3.30 extension 19) to my ASUS laptop, I have downloaded the "sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell".

I downloaded the KDE app to my Samsung J2 Pro, and it seems to work.

I have extracted the zip archive, but it is not working, my phone shows "No devices". (even after a reboot of the laptop).

I'm using MATE on Ubuntu 18.04. I cannot find GSConnect listed anywhere on my laptop other than in the  Downloads folder, it shows a folder with 11 items, some of which are also folders.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Hal.

Comment: GSConnect is an extension for GNOME 3 shell, not sure if it's supposed to work with MATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use gsconnect with mate. You can however use the regular kde connect. Just add this ppa as described [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2017/04/new-kde-connect-indicator-ubuntu-linux.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/indicator-kdeconnect
sudo apt-get update
```

then:

```
sudo apt install kdeconnect indicator-kdeconnect
```

Now start the indicator from the app menu and you should be good to go.